# When was Proto-Austronesian spoken?

Tags: historical-linguistics, reconstruction, austronesian

I read on Wikipedia that the language that Hawaiian comes from, distantly, is called Proto-Austronesian. It says that it had more sounds/phonemes was spoken around Taiwan and Southern China. However, I searched for when it was spoken, and there was no information on that topic, or even the word BC for that matter. So, when was it spoken?

Comment: As @Draconis put it recently [in another answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/34136/482), a Proto-language is not really a language, but a reconstruction, sort of like a stick-figure drawing of _The Last Supper_. It almost certainly does not describe any language that was ever spoken by a single human being; maybe one or two dialects, but which ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This map from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austronesian_languages#/media/File:Chronological_dispersal_of_Austronesian_people_across_the_Pacific_(per_Bellwood_in_Chambers,_2008).png) assigns dates to the Austronesian expansion, and Proto-Austronesian on Taiwan dates back to before 3000 BC. The line below the map says that the dates are coming from archeological findings and aren't determined by linguistic methods.

Comment: That was a very nice description.